# ConstraintLayout: place TextView below ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm faced with the seemingly simple task of having a layout with:

- An `ImageView` taking the full width, height according to image's aspect ratio
- a `TextView` below that

This is what I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hamster"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the `ImageView` has a margin to the top which I do not want.

If I change the `ImageView's` constraints from

```
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

to

```
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

(removing the bottom constraint), the result looks like this:

[image]

Now the `ImageView` is at the very top of my layout, but the `TextView` has gone. Mind you, for the second variant, Android Studio 3's layout preview shows the layout exactly as I would want it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Note: The layout needs to be `ConstraintLayout` and the layout's height has to be `wrap_content`.

You can find my test project [here](https://github.com/fweigl/Constraintthrowaway).

**EDIT: The problem seems to occur only on larger devices. I'm using the Nexus 9 emulator.**

Comment: Did you try using `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=0.0`

Comment: @Ascorbin ,nirva shah's solution's work??

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Nope, see my comment below his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as Akash Amin said add this two line in your ImageView

```
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
```

Comment: Adding this to the ImageView fixed the problem, thanks.

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this it was helpful for you

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

[image]

Comment: The outcome of this is http://i66.tinypic.com/24nps1e.jpg, so unfortunately not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText "
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Delete bootom contraint of imageview and set textview top constraint to bottom of imageview

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists with your xml on larger devices. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText 
        MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText 
        MyText 
        MyText MText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText 
        MyText 
        MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MText MyText MyText 
        MyText 
        MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText MyText t 
        MyText MyText MyText MyText "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.